# Problem when Adding stateListAnimator to Recyclerview items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I am trying to add elevation animation to my items on recyclerview. I saw examples online but they were for hard defined cards.

I added animator to `res/animator`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="56dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="0dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

after that I handled my each recyclerview item click in adapter.

```
class RecyclerViewAdapterMainDashboard(
    private val features: List<MainDashboardModel>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterMainDashboard.DashboardViewHolder>() {
    inner class DashboardViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val imageUrlMain: ImageView = itemView.imageCity
        val textTitle: TextView = itemView.textTitleCity

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DashboardViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.main_dashboard_cards, parent, false)
        return DashboardViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return features.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DashboardViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = features[position]
        holder.textTitle.text = currentItem.cityMain
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load(currentItem.imageUrlMain)
            .fitCenter()
            .into(holder.imageUrlMain)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {


            when (currentItem.cityId) {
                1 -> {
                    val stateListAnimator: StateListAnimator =
                        AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(
                            it.context,
                            R.animator.elevation_on_touch
                        )
                    holder.itemView.stateListAnimator = stateListAnimator
                    val intent = Intent(it.context, CityActivityNewYork::class.java)
                    it.context.startActivity(intent)

                }
                2 -> {
                    val stateListAnimator: StateListAnimator =
                        AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(
                            it.context,
                            R.animator.elevation_on_touch
                        )
                    holder.itemView.stateListAnimator = stateListAnimator
                    val intent = Intent(it.context, CityActivityHawaii::class.java)
                    it.context.startActivity(intent)

                }
                3 -> {
                    val stateListAnimator: StateListAnimator =
                        AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(
                            it.context,
                            R.animator.elevation_on_touch
                        )
                    holder.itemView.stateListAnimator = stateListAnimator
                    val intent = Intent(it.context, CityActivityIstanbul::class.java)
                    it.context.startActivity(intent)


                }
                4 -> {
                    val stateListAnimator: StateListAnimator =
                        AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(
                            it.context,
                            R.animator.elevation_on_touch
                        )
                    holder.itemView.stateListAnimator = stateListAnimator
                    val intent = Intent(it.context, CityActivityBolivia::class.java)
                    it.context.startActivity(intent)

                }


            }


        }


    }
}
```

Also I added these attributes to card.xml

```
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/elevation_on_touch"
```

The problem is cards are not elevating when I pressed the cards. Even I write 54dp to see if they are moving but nothing happened. Should I add something to recyclerview component itself? What am I doing wrong ?

[project repo](https://github.com/CanerGures/CityCatalog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your `selector`, you've made `state_enabled="true"` and `state_pressed="true"` for both selector states. But `state_pressed` should be `true` only for pressed state. Correct selector should look like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true">
        ...
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false">
         .....
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I tried to add animator to recycler view itself also didn't work.I will put github to question link can you check please ?